# How do I block SWT UI thread while waiting for server response

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have a SWT UI with OK and Cancel buttons. When I press OK on the UI, a server call is made and depending on server response I would like to proceed. How do I block UI thread from going forward and wait for server response.

I have seen a similar post here: [eclipse rcp : how to block ui while running a job in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660574/eclipse-rcp-how-to-block-ui-while-running-a-job-in-background)
But the link in the answer doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I have a long task to do and I want my user to wait, I use this construct :

```
BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getCurrent(), new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
           // long operation, for example fetch a distant resource
    }
});
```

This blocks the UI and set the cursor as a hourglass.

Comment: Thanks. This is implemented in UI thread? and anyway I do not want a busy indicator because my task is not that long. Is there any other way to block UI?

Comment: Yes, that's launched from the UI thread. There's no problem in doing it if the task takes only one second.